# Cannot handle event that has been raised from other script

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have 2 scripts, scriptA will raise the event when I destroy an game object, and scriptB will handle the event. But it didn't work. Here are my 2 scripts:

ScriptA:

```
public delegate void DestroyCallback(GameObject obj);
public event DestroyCallback OnObjDestroy;
public void DestroyObjEvent(GameObject obj)
{
    if (OnObjDestroy != null)
        OnObjDestroy(obj);
}
 
void DestroyButtonClick()
{
    DestroyObjEvent(obj);
}
```

Script B:

```
ScriptA scriptAInstance = new ScriptA();
 
void DestroyObjHandler(GameObject obj)
{
     Debug.Log(obj.name);
}
 
void Start()
{      
    selectObjInstance.OnObjDestroy += DestroyObjHandler;
}
```

When I debug, the event was call, but I cannot call to the DestroyObjHandler function. It still didn't work even when i tried putting the "selectObjInstance.OnObjDestroy += DestroyObjHandler;" line inside Update(). Please help.

When I debug, the event was call, but I cannot call to the DestroyObjHandler function. It still didn't work even when i tried putting the "selectObjInstance.OnObjDestroy += DestroyObjHandler;" line inside Update(). Please help.

Comment: normally in unity new is not used with a monobehavior so given these are mock classes - perhaps thats the issue, or the fact that you dont use scriptA in scriptB but selectObjeInstaqnce which is unddefined? far too much vauge to give accurate help. You dont seem to trigger your own event, so it really is hard

Comment: You forgot to `Invoke` event.  Use this instead `OnObjDestroy.Invoke(obj);`

Comment: Can you, please, provide the real code you're trying to run? Compilable one.